# Is there a way in subversion to tell parent branch

Tags: svn

Is there a way to tell parent branch in subversion? I have two branches BranchA and BranchB
I want to be able to tell their parent branch (from which branch was it originally copied).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can see copy/merge/tag points via `svn log -v --stop-on-copy`.  The `-v` is verbose, showing which paths were changed and that is where you'll see the copy from location and revision.  `--stop-on-copy` is there to avoid walking past the most recent copy.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using `TortoiseSVN`, this information is available through its UI.

- Select the branch you want, right click and select `Show log` option from TortoiseSVN's context menu
- [OPTIONAL] To limit the logs, you can select the checkbox `Stop on copy/rename`
- Select the commit in which you created the branch, and just take a look at the affected files section (below commit message)

For new branches, it should mention: `Path`, `Action`, `Copy from path`, `Revision`

The information you need is under `Copy from path` column.

Example:
[image]